# Ms Access SQL Update statement doesn't work

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I currently have a split default view

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L9HP.png)]

I'm trying to change the field "Email verzonden?" from "Niet verzonden!" to "Verzonden!" when the user presses a button, but only when the checkbox in front of it is checked.

I tried to use an update statement with SQL but I get the following error code:

> Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Does anyone know how to fix this and how to get it to work?
This is the SQL that I'm using:

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "Update artikelfiche SET Verzonden = 'Verzonden!' WHERE Bestellen = -1"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nevermind, I found it immediately after posting this, sorry for the question. I forgot the '' at '-1'..

Comment: What type is `Verzonden` and ` Bestellen` in your DB?

Comment: It's fine, already fixed it myself. Thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: @Athemoe: if you think this question might be helpful to other StackOverflow users, please answer your own question!

Answer (score 0):

I should look better before posting questions.
This is the solution though:

Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "Update artikelfiche SET Verzonden = 'Verzonden!' WHERE Bestellen = '-1'"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End Sub

Basically, I forgot the '' at the criteria of Bestellen.